# Calling external php scripts returns a blank page

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am running a cakePHP app that has to call external php scripts. Controller action flow looks like this:

```
if($this->saveRepeatedEvents($event, $employees, $weekdays)){

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('All good'));

    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=>'index'));
}

function saveRepeatedEvents($event, $employees, $weekdays){

    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gcm_server_php/Notifications.php';

        $notifications = new Notifications;


        //Save single event for every employee and every day

            ...code omitted...

        $notifications->send_notification($employees,$eventId,$numberOfEvents);

        return true;
    }
```

The external scripts are and called everything works well, but after that I get either a blank screen (if script does not return anything) or a string echoed by the script. What I want to happen is after the script is called, the controller to proceed with the normal flow and redirect user to another view.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you include Notifications.php in your Vendors?

Comment: Check your logs. White page means usually some kind of fatal error.

Comment: Both error and debug logs are empty, no erros. And the external scripts are executed well, seems like there are no problems.